# Laravel order data by relation property

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two related models 'Yards' & 'Inspections'. A yard can have multiple inspections.

I want to be able to order the Yard list based on the inspection property 'reinspect_at'. I have a Model method that returns the Latest Inspection for the yard based on the inspection date.

I have tried the following:

```
$yards = Yard::orderBy('quarantined', 'DESC')
        ->with(['latestInspection' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('reinspect_at', 'asc');
        }])
        ->get();
```

But this doesn't order the yard based on the reinspect_at date, it is only ordering the latest inspection for each yard.

I want to be able to always return the latest inspection for the yard, but need to be able to reorder the yard list based on the reinspect_at date for the latest inspection for each yard. Cheers

Screenshot of yard list display below. As you can see the Inspection due date is how I want to be able to order the result.

[image]

** Update **
Looks like what I want is possible in the frontend template using:

```
@foreach( $yards->sortBy('latestInspection.reinspect_at') as $yard )
```

It would be preferable to do be able to do this from the controller though, so I can have other options for ordering by.

Comment: i am using datatable plugin for sorting...can you show a screenshot of a result that you get

Comment: Have added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can do the following:

```
$yards = Yard::orderBy('quarantined', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('archived', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
$yards = $yards->sortByDesc('latestInspection.reinspect_at');
```

Comment: Yes, this line:
`$yards = $yards->sortByDesc('latestInspection.reinspect_at');`
Sorts it based on the relation date

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
function latestInspection() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Yard')->orderBy('reinspect_at', 'asc');
}
```

And

```
$yards = Yard::with('latestInspection')->orderBy('quarantined', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Hi, this way only orders the inspection for each yard, I want to order the yard list based on the reinspect_at date from the latest inspection.
i.e
yard 1 - 01-01-2016
yard 2 - 02-01-2016

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of the methods of the returned collection.  Generally you want to handle this all on the database end but I think this way is worth it because it greatly simplifies the process.

```
$yards = Yard::with(['inspections'])->get()->sortBy(function($yard) {
    return $yard->inspections->max('reinspect_at');
});
```

I removed your ordering by quarantine.  Not sure how you want to handle that if you are also sorting by the reinspect_date.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this doesn't seem to make a difference to the ordering of the list of yards.